# Moving spam from filter to mail server

Tags: scripting, email-server, spamassassin

I was wondering if its possible to take messages quarantined by a Spamassassin box and move it to the users spam folder residing on an email server. In my case I would want to move mail from an Untangle box to my Zimbra ZCS box.

I was thinking some kind of a script but I am not even sure of the procedure that would have to take place. Or whether it is even possible to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the question is not "can you" but "why would you want to"?

The advantages of having a spam/virus filter out in front of your mailserver are a) you reduce load on the server, both in terms of storage and processor load, b) to quarantine anything nasty that might infect your mailserver and/or user machine.

Filtering the mail, and then pushing it to the server does remove some processing load from the mailserver, but you still have the issues of extra storage and viruses/malware potentially ending up on client machines.

Comment: Ah... I did not really think about that part, good point. The reason would want to this is so users would be able to look in one central place for all spam rather than having to access an outside quarantine. Follow me? But based on what you are saying it would be better to just have the spam filter stay the way it is as it would be safer.

Comment: @Solignis It's (theoretically) better to force the users to take a conscious action (access external quarantine & release a message). (again, Theoretically) It means they're more likely to be cognizant of what they're doing and (hopefully) more likely to be skeptical of that plea from a deposed Nigerian prince...

Comment: I tend to think it's a better arrangement - all of my clients have some form of external filtering system, whether that be Postini or a hardware appliance (i.e. Barracuda), out in front of their mailservers.  I should also point out - your users DO have a cetnral place for spam - it's the quarantine service.  If they unquarantine mail, it's no longer spam. :)

Comment: @Driftpeasant, good point I guess it is a central place. Well it sounds like the idea of leaving the filter as is would be a better move. Thanks for the help